# Creating multiple signed url for multiple objects of AWS S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

Can we create multiple signed URL of S3(AWS), for multiple object in single request in node.js. Suppose there is a need to generate 100 signed URL for accessing 100 objects and for that we are using getSignedUrl() function of AWS -sdk  which is called 100 times. Can we do it in an optimize manner and reduce the request counts?

Answer (score 14):

getSignedUrl() does not actually make a request. It is implemented entirely locally.